# Load JS widget in Angular View

Tags: ajax, angularjs, widget

I have a widget that I want to plug into my angular view. I'm not sure I'm explaining it right but the code I get from the site that makes/hosts the widget is below:

```
<script src="http://www.somesite.com/widgetfile.js"></script>
```

This works perfectly fine on a standard html site (just a simple html file loaded locally in my browser). It loads the external JS file and does a document.write onto my DOM as far as I can tell.

The problem I'm having is putting this on a view in an Angular app I've built. I thought it would be the same thing as just copy/pasting the single line of script that the site gave me, but it doesn't work... error i get is below (Chrome).

Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

I can't use something other than document.write because I don't have access to the file itself, the site that generates the widget does that for me. I've tried doing $http get request in my controller than putting that to a scope variable to be put on the DOM, but I get an error about cross domain security.

Any thoughts? This seems super basic to me since there are thousands of sites that offer "One line of code to embed a widget"... and it works in basic HTML pages. Am I missing something stupid (keep in mind that yes, I did copy and paste the widget script directly from the site that hosts it).

Thanks for the help. I'm pretty new with coding and newer at angular, but this seems like something that should be borderline plug-n-play and not need some complex cross domain workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try these with these two links.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-widget
https://github.com/cztomsik/ng-widgets